# list data structure split across files?

Tags: list, persistence

If I were trying to use a list as a data structure -- and it was getting really big -- is there a precedent of breaking it up and having it span files? One particular list of mine is looking very tree-ish (as Treebeard might say), and it's getting huge. I know I should just think "graph theory" and have branches of the tree in one file "linked" (edged) to others, but I thought I'd ask here for guidance, experiences on list size issues and handling in the real world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you could do that. You'll have to walk the graph yourself, deciding which parts go in which file, and marking the links between them so that you can reread everything correctly; it'll be a pretty big chunk of work.

Are you sure it's worth it? Modern computers can handle terabyte-sized files with no sweat; these are far larger than the data structures you can fit directly in memory will be. Even if the files are too big, running them through gzip or bzip2 will be far simpler, and may save enough to let you avoid all of that work.

If file size is truly important and compression isn't enough, then I would investigate using a binary file format rather than text.

Comment: I'm beginning to not like org-mode and how my "data" (stuff?) in the org-mode outline format is not based on an elegant data structure. Just look at MS Word and how it's not all that intelligent (or moved any mountains) with its outline philosophy. But then org-mode developers have created org-dp and org-element to try to address this inelegance. Was a big org-mode fan, but now I'm toying with just throwing everything (text, code, data) I'm doing into a Big List shaped like "graph-n`-trees", then writing code (also embedded in Big List) that deals with it. One list to rule them all!

Comment: This isn't a new sentiment :) Check out Xanadu and ZigZag, for instance, or the Lisp Machines.

Comment: Gosh, I'm trying to reinvent the wheel here, I guess. But he (Ted Nelson) doesn't seem to talk about graph theory. In general, I think Emacs is uniquely qualified because you can change anything on running buffers.

Comment: It may be harder to find information about ZigZag (though I believe there are some videos on Youtube). It's a fairly complicated data structure for implementing graphs of a particular nature. He, like you, wanted everything to be in this regular structure to make navigation, editing, viewing, etc uniform across all the data you might have in your computer. Lisp's cons cells are a much simpler way to go about it, but ZigZag would give you a much richer set of interconnections between individual pieces of data.